# Active record to select row from two table from specific condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to select rows from two table using specific condition in code igniter.

I used this code.But its not working. Please help me.

```
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('post_response');
 $this->db->where('post_response.user_id', $response_id);  //$repsonse_id has value from contoller
 $this->db->join('register','register.id = post_response.user_id'); 
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
```

I have value in these tables but this return an empty array.

Tables:

### Post_reponse

user_id | message

18      | something

### register

id | name |

18 | john |

### Output should be:

id | message  | name

18 | somthing | john

Comment: are you sure its `post_response.user_id = $response_id`? maybe `post_response.response_id = $response_id`

Comment: No, I am sure that the condition is correct but it returns empty.

Comment: Use $query->last_query(); and verify it on mysql whether your query working or not in mysql.

Comment: its not working in mysql query also. What might be wrong with my query

Comment: There are 2 options why this will not work: 1. JOIN is preventing 2. WHERE clause is preventing. Or both, but even one is enough. If you post the content of the tables we can help you more!

Comment: i found solution for myself. Answer is posted

Answer (score 0):

Hi I ended up with solution after the research. This could be helpful to other. Below are my database table with the result I wanted with solution.

[image: Sql table and result]

This the modal of the ci where $response_id is from controller:

```
 function get_comments_by_product_id($response_id)
 {        
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT post_response.*, register.* FROM post_response LEFT JOIN register ON post_response.user_id = register.id where post_response.product_id= ?;", array($response_id));
    return $query->result();
 }
```